# Mockito running independently works but fail when run together

Tags: mockito

I'm mocking the jdbc connection, resultset and PreparedStatment.

So, when a run the tests one-by-one works. But if a run all tests from class the method `whenSelectB` fail.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: There are 2 rows
Expected: <2>
     but: was <0>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at net.sf.jkniv.whinstone.jdbc.dml.MockitoSample.whenSelectB(MockitoSample.java:155)
```

There is some trick to run this?

```java
public class MockitoSample
{        
    private DataSource        dataSource;
    private Connection        connection;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;
    private ResultSet         rs;
    private ResultSetMetaData rsMetadata;
    private DatabaseMetaData  dbMetadata;

    private RepositoryConfig  repositoryConfig;
    private SqlContext        sqlContext;
    private Selectable        sql;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException
    {
        this.connection = mock(Connection.class);
        this.dataSource = mock(DataSource.class);
        this.stmt = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
        this.rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
        this.rsMetadata = mock(ResultSetMetaData.class);
        this.dbMetadata = mock(DatabaseMetaData.class);
        this.repositoryConfig = mock(RepositoryConfig.class);
        this.sqlContext = mock(SqlContext.class);
        this.sql = mock(Selectable.class);

        given(this.dataSource.getConnection()).willReturn(this.connection);
        given(this.connection.prepareStatement(anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt())).willReturn(this.stmt);
        given(this.stmt.executeQuery()).willReturn(this.rs);
        given(this.stmt.executeQuery(anyString())).willReturn(this.rs);
        given(this.dbMetadata.getJDBCMajorVersion()).willReturn(1);
        given(this.dbMetadata.getJDBCMinorVersion()).willReturn(0);
        given(this.dbMetadata.getDriverName()).willReturn("MOCKITO");
        given(this.dbMetadata.getDriverVersion()).willReturn("1");

        given(this.rs.getMetaData()).willReturn(this.rsMetadata);

        given(this.repositoryConfig.getName()).willReturn("Mockito");
        given(this.repositoryConfig.lookup()).willReturn(this.dataSource);
        given(this.repositoryConfig.getJndiDataSource()).willReturn("jdbc/Mockito");
        given(this.repositoryConfig.getProperty(RepositoryProperty.JDBC_ADAPTER_FACTORY.key()))
                .willReturn(DataSourceAdapter.class.getName());
        given(this.repositoryConfig.getTransactionType()).willReturn(TransactionType.LOCAL);
        given(this.repositoryConfig.getQueryNameStrategy()).willReturn("net.sf.jkniv.sqlegance.HashQueryNameStrategy");

        given(this.sql.getValidateType()).willReturn(ValidateType.NONE);
        given(this.sql.getSql(any())).willReturn("select * from dual");
        given(this.sql.getSqlDialect()).willReturn(new AnsiDialect());
        given(this.sql.getParamParser()).willReturn(ParamParserFactory.getInstance(ParamMarkType.COLON));
        given(this.sql.getStats()).willReturn(NoSqlStats.getInstance());
        given(this.sql.getSqlType()).willReturn(SqlType.SELECT);
        given(this.sql.asSelectable()).willReturn((Selectable) this.sql);

        given(this.sqlContext.getRepositoryConfig()).willReturn(this.repositoryConfig);
        given(this.sqlContext.getQuery(anyString())).willReturn(this.sql);

    }

    @Test
    public void whenSelectA() throws SQLException
    {
        Repository repository = RepositoryService.getInstance().lookup(RepositoryType.JDBC).newInstance(sqlContext);
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnCount()).willReturn(2);
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnLabel(1)).willReturn("id");
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnName(1)).willReturn("id");
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnLabel(2)).willReturn("name");
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnName(2)).willReturn("name");
        given(this.rs.getMetaData()).willReturn(this.rsMetadata);
        given(this.sql.getReturnType()).willReturn(FlatBook.class.getName());
        doReturn(FlatBook.class).when(this.sql).getReturnTypeAsClass();
        given(rs.next()).willReturn(true, true, false);
        given(rs.getObject(1)).willReturn(1001L, 1002L);
        given(rs.getObject(2)).willReturn("Beyond Good and Evil", "The Rebel: An Essay on Man in Revolt");

        Queryable q = QueryFactory.of("2 FlatBook");
        List<FlatBook> books = repository.list(q);
        assertThat("There are 2 rows", books.size(), equalTo(2));
        assertThat("Row is a FlatBook object", books.get(0), instanceOf(FlatBook.class));
        for (FlatBook b : books)
        {
            assertThat(b.getId(), notNullValue());
            assertThat(b.getName(), notNullValue());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void whenSelectB() throws SQLException
    {
        Repository repository = RepositoryService.getInstance().lookup(RepositoryType.JDBC).newInstance(sqlContext);
        given(rsMetadata.getColumnCount()).willReturn(2);
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnLabel(1)).willReturn("id");
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnName(1)).willReturn("id");
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnLabel(2)).willReturn("name");
        given(this.rsMetadata.getColumnName(2)).willReturn("name");
        given(this.rs.getMetaData()).willReturn(this.rsMetadata);
        given(this.sql.getReturnType()).willReturn(FlatAuthor.class.getName());
        doReturn(FlatAuthor.class).when(this.sql).getReturnTypeAsClass();
        given(rs.next()).willReturn(true, true, false);
        given(rs.getObject(1)).willReturn(1L, 2L);
        given(rs.getObject(2)).willReturn("Author 1", "Author 2");

        Queryable q = QueryFactory.of("2 FlatAuthor");
        List<FlatAuthor> books = repository.list(q);
        assertThat("There are 2 rows", books.size(), equalTo(2));
        assertThat("Row is a FlatAuthor object", books.get(0), instanceOf(FlatAuthor.class));
        for (FlatAuthor a : books)
        {
            assertThat(a.getId(), notNullValue());
            assertThat(a.getName(), notNullValue());
        }
        verify(rs).close();
        verify(stmt).close();
        verify(connection, atLeast(1)).close();
    }
```

The error happens inside the `Repository` instance, it uses the`rs.next ()`(ResultSet) method but returns`false` when it should return `true` twice.

Comment: You have a setUp method and a lot of instance variables but no tearDown method so implement that and set all variables to null as a start. Another option is to skip all variables and use local variables instead (maybe with some factory methods)

Comment: I did try this is doesn't works. I did try too to make all local instance variables and got same problem :(

Comment: Ok. What about this RepositoryService, have you checked that you handle it correctly? It looks like a singleton to me.

Comment: you right, RepsitoryService is singleton, but Repository not, it handle the jdbc object (connection, Statement and ResultSet)... the problem is that given(rs.next()).willReturn(true, true, false) return false when should return true!

Comment: 1 test is probably dirting the context.

Comment: Have you tried to call close() on the result set at the end of the test or in tearDown? Or any other closable JDBC resource for that matter

Comment: yes, you was right Is hold the datasource from whenSelectA.

Answer (score 0):

My Repository instance holds the `DataSouce` class in the`ThreadLocal`, so when `whenSelectB` tries to get the new Mock it retrieves the old DataSource that retrieves the old Connection, which gets the old Statement that retrieves the old ResultSet. In other words, I have a dirty context between test. Repository must hold the connection just when a transaction was began.

Thanks @Joakim-Danielson and @Antoniossss